# Can I add returned CLLocationDistance into an NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using the below body of code to find the distances between a logged in user and a list of other users in my app's database.

**ViewController.h**

```
@property (nonatomic) CLLocationDistance kilometers;
```

**ViewController.m**

```
NSString *myLocation = self.currentUser[0][@"street_address"];
                NSLog(@"MY LOCATION %@", myLocation);


                CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
                [geocoder geocodeAddressString:myLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks2, NSError* error){
                    for (CLPlacemark* aPlacemark in placemarks2)
                    {

for (NSMutableDictionary *multiplelocationsFriend in self.closeByNeighbours) {

NSString *location = [multiplelocationsFriend objectForKey:@"address"];

CLGeocoder *geocoderFriend = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
                            [geocoderFriend geocodeAddressString:location
                                               completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
                                                   if (placemarks && placemarks.count > 0) {
                                                       CLPlacemark *topResult = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                                                       MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithPlacemark:topResult];


                                                         self.endLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:placemark.location.coordinate.latitude longitude:placemark.location.coordinate.longitude] ;


                                                        NSString *myLocation = self.currentUser[0][@"street_address"];
                                                        NSLog(@"MY LOCATION %@", myLocation);

CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[geocoder geocodeAddressString:myLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks2, NSError* error){
                                                        for (CLPlacemark* aPlacemark in placemarks2)
                                                        {
 self.startLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:aPlacemark.location.coordinate.latitude longitude:aPlacemark.location.coordinate.longitude] ;

                                                       self.kilometers = [self.startLocation distanceFromLocation:self.endLocation] / 1000;


                                                        }
                                                        }];


                                                   }
                                               }
                             ];
                        }

                    }
                }];




                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [self.neighboursView reloadData];
                });



            } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"Failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }];
```

Is there any way to add self.kilometers into an NSMutableArray? When I try doing it, XCode throws me an error saying:

> Sending 'CLLocationDistance' (aka 'double') to parameter of
>   incompatible type 'id _Nonnull'

Comment: The thumb rule is you can not add primitive datatypes into the array. The arrays are pointers, can store objects. `CLLocationDistance` is a `double` (which is primitive datatype), so before adding to an array, you must have to convert it to object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert it to an `NSNumber`.

```c
NSMutableArray *a = [NSMutableArray new];
[a addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:self.kilometers]];
```

Answer (score 0):

The entries in an `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray` must all be object pointers. `nil` pointers and non-object types (e.g. `int`, `double`, `CGPoint`) are not allowed.

- To put a placeholder into a mutable array, use the `NSNull` class
  (instead of trying to put a `nil` into the array).
- To put things like `CGPoint` into a mutable array, use the `NSValue`
  class.
- To put primitive types like `int` and `double` into a mutable array,
  use the `NSNumber` class.

So in your case, since `CLLocationDistance` is actually a `double`, you need to encapsulate the distance in a `NSNumber` object, and then add the `NSNumber` object to the array. To retrieve the distance, take the `NSNumber` object from the array, and extract the `double`.

Here's an example that shows the whole process:

```
// create a mutable array
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray new];

// encapsulate a CLLocationDistance (actually a 'double') in a NSNumber, and add the NSNumber to the array
CLLocationDistance distance1 = 2.1;
NSNumber *number1 = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:distance1];
[array addObject:number1];
NSLog(@"%@", array);

// get the NSNumber from the array and unpack the 'double' value
NSNumber *number2 = [array firstObject];
CLLocationDistance distance2 = [number2 doubleValue];
NSLog(@"the distance is %lf", distance2);
```

Here's the output:

> 2019-08-28 14:02:32.197 TestSomething[1195:476743] (
>       "2.1"
>   )
>   2019-08-28 14:02:32.198 TestSomething[1195:476743] the distance is 2.100000